# Can we use exit() function in C while working with embedded systems

Tags: c, embedded, coding-style, exit

I am working on a project related to embedded systems and wanted to know if it is a good practice to use the function exit(0) in your program.

```
        if (Req[0] == '0')
        {
            puts("Emergency stop button operated\n");
            **exit(0);**
        }
```

Comment: The answer to this is particular to your system and your project. Certainly `exit` is a standard C function, and that means it is available for use in a standard C implementation. Whether it is available in your C implementation, whether using it is suitable for meeting the goals and requirements of your project, and what effect it will have in the systems depends on your C implementation, your project, and those systems. If you do not know, you should ask the people specifying the project requirements.

Comment: In general, when your target is a bare-metal environment (without operating system), you would usually _never_ terminate your application. That's because, without an operating system, there really isn't much you could return _*to*_ except for the startup code which called `main` in the first place. And how that startup code behaves if `main` ever returns is entirely platform dependent (it might stop in an infinite loop, it might perform a soft-reset, who knows)

Comment: @EricPostpischil A conforming freestanding implementation need not provide stdlib.h. See C17 4/6.

Comment: Also, since your code snippet mentions an emergency stop button, i'm pretty sure your application is expected to handle such an event in an appropriate manner, and i can't imagine just terminating the application would be appropriate. Imagine for example a servo controller controlling heavy machinery. If the user slams the emergency stop, then the servo controller must react to that 1) as fast as possible and 2) in a well defined manner. In such a case, terminating the application would be equivalent to saying "oops, i don't know what to do", and could very well cost someone their life.

Comment: What would you expect to happen when you call exit on your embedded system?

Answer (score 3):

`exit`, as well as returning from `main()`, only makes sense in hosted systems where there is an OS to return to. Most embedded systems do not have that, but are so-called "freestanding" systems: "bare metal" or RTOS microcontroller applications. A compiler for such a system need not provide `stdlib.h` so the function `exit` might not even be available.

The normal way to handle errors in such systems is to implement a custom error handler, which can log or print the error. And from there on in case of critical errors, you usually provoke a watchdog reset, leading to a full system re-boot. This is because errors in embedded systems are often hardware-related, and a watchdog reset doesn't just restore the software to default, but also all MCU registers and peripheral hardware connected to the MCU.

In high integrity embedded systems, such as the ones that actually have a real emergency stop, it is however common to keep the program running but revert it to a safe state. The MCU keeps running but all dangerous outputs etc are disabled, either to allow the system to get shut down in a controlled manner, or to "limp home" and keep running as well as it is still capable of. Writing software for such system is quite a big topic of its own.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, as @Felix G said in comment: If you work with an operating system, `exit(0);` is relevant, if you work with bare-metal application, no.

Please refer to @Felix G comment for more details.

By the way `**exit(0);**` is not a correct statement in C. You may mean `exit(0);` or `/*exit(0);*/`.

Comment: The `**` stuff is likely just an attempt at emphasis with **bold** (`**bold**`) formatting for the SO site. It doesn't work inside code formatting.